# Why FileSystemView throw NPE in my scenario

Tags: java, teamcity

I'm using Java to get the map between volume label and drive letter and the code is like below:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
public class Test{

    public void listMap(){
        File[] files = File.listRoots();
        System.out.println("The map between volume label and drive is: " );
        for(File file: files){
            String theMap = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(file);
            System.out.println(theMap);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.listMap();
    }
}
```

I have built above code into a exe file on windows through exe4j. It works fine when you run it directly.
However, when I use `Teamcity` build agent to launch the exe, the exception below will be thrown when the `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(file)` is called.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Well you're using a UI-based class in an environment that probably doesn't have access to a UI. The fact that the problem is in Win32ShellFloder2 strongly suggests that's the problem. I would try to avoid using anything from Swing in a headless environment.

Comment: How exactly do you start the `exe` on TeamCity agent?
Did you try to copy command line reported in the build log and to paste it locally, to see if it works?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your comment, maybe I need to find a workaround.

Comment: Or try to avoid needing that sort of information within a CI system. It feels like a fairly odd requirement to me.

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov Yep, I have tried to launch the exe with command line on the agent directly and it works fine. I have written a customized plugin which is integrated into Teamcity. The plugin will accept the exe as the ProgramCommandLine and launch the exe when relative build is triggered.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it's odd cause I'm doing something about a test infrastructure which is managed by Teamcity, the infrastructure itself needs the volume label info. It's not really like a traditional build. ^_^

Comment: @Gearon try launching the TeamCity agent explicitly using *.bat scripts and see, if you can run the build on such agent.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your reminder, I abandoned the FileSystemView from Swing package and implemented same function with cpp, finally, used JNI to call the native side.

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov Thanks, I tried the workaround with JNI and the error exception disappears.