# What's the workaround to get the map between volume label and drive letter in java instead of FileSystemView

Tags: java

It's feasible to get the map between volume label and drive letter in java by code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
public class Test{

    public void listMap(){
        File[] files = File.listRoots();
        System.out.println("The map between volume label and drive is: " );
        for(File file: files){
            String theMap = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(file);
            System.out.println(theMap);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.listMap();
    }
}
```

However, it's not a workable solution for me since [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616912/why-filesystemview-throw-npe-in-my-scenario),  the usage of `FileSystemView` will lead to the `NPE` in my scenario. So here comes my question, how to get the map between volume lavel and drive letter in java instead of `FileSystemView`? I have googled a lot but found nothing without the usage of `FileSystemView`. Maybe the last workaround is to write the native code to get the map and using JNI to calling from java.

Answer (score 0):

Finally chosen to implement it in native side and used JNI(Java Native Interface) to get the map.

I wants the function on Windows so [GetLogicalDrives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972(v=vs.85).aspx) is served as `File[] files = File.listRoots();`, after that, [GetVolumeInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx) is used to get the volume label from drive.

Post the solution for those who might meet the same issue.